holoviews how to set margin around a layout
Using holoviews with the plotly extension, I am rendering a layout with several overlay plots.  Each plot has a 4 line title. Unfortunately, the result clips the title from 4 lines to two.  It feels like I need to set margins but doing so does not seem to help.  How can I make it so that all of the title shows?
This is a simplified example code with the result.
height = 500
width = 500

x = range(0,21)
y = [3.00 + 0.500*i for i in x]

data = pd.DataFrame(zip(x,y),columns=['x','y'])
lin_reg = hv.Scatter(data).opts(height=height, width=width
                                , color='red'
                                , marker='diamond', size=3
                               )


title = "Pearson={} <br>Spearman={} <br>Kendall={} <br>Xi={}".format(1, 2, 3, 4)
temp = hv.Scatter(data).opts(title=title, height=height, width=width
                            , margins=(10, 100, 10, 100))

final = temp * lin_reg

hv.Layout([final]).cols(1).opts(shared_axes=False, width=800)



I think the margin setting is disabled when overlaying, as the title appears correctly when placed side by side, not overlaid, with the correct margin modification. How about raising the issue with the developer?

@r-beginners agree and have raised issue
